# JS code failing for large inputs in online judge

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I got a question which as follows:
You've given two strings s1 and s2 where

`1 <= s1.length <= 100000, s2.length = s1.length+1`

both strings have lowercase alphabets only [a-z]. s1 and s2 have same amount of characters just shuffled in any order. But s2 has one extra char, and we've to print it.

Input format as follows:

```
string1
string2
```

This is my code in JS(here process.stdin is default code provided in online editor):

```js
const stdin = process.openStdin() ; // default in code editor

let str1, str2 ;
stdin.setEncoding('utf-8') ; // added
stdin.addListener('data', (d) => { // this listener was default
    [str1, str2] = d.split('\n') ;
}) ;

stdin.addListener('end', () => { // added
    let code = str2.charCodeAt(0) ;

    for(let i=1; i<str2.length; i++){
        code += (str2.charCodeAt(i) - str1.charCodeAt(i-1)) ;
    }

    console.log(String.fromCharCode(code)) ;
}) ;
```

For small string lengths let's say s1: abcd, s2: abcde it shows correctly 'e'.

But larger strings closing near 10^5 this was giving runtime error.

Same code in C++, was passing all test cases.:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main(){
    string s1, s2 ;
    cin >> s1 >> s2 ;
    int code = int(s2[0]) ;
    for(int i=1; s2[i] != '\0'; i++){
        code += (int(s2[i]) - int(s1[i-1])) ;
    }
    cout << char(code) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

So, to check locally ran the same code with file.txt having string `s1.length = 10^5-1 and s2.length = 10^5`

Ran the command as follows:

Node.js: node script.js < file.txt

[image: failed nodejs screenshot]

I want to know the reason why the sdtin stream is undefined for large value and possibly how to tackle these kinds of case.

Comment: You did not take into account that the `data` event can be emitted multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @Botje's comment, for large files, data listener is running multiple times. Created a single variable to add all chunks. Then ran my logic again, got correct answer. Thanks for the hint !

Code:

```
const stdin = process.openStdin() ;

let stream = '' ;
stdin.setEncoding('utf-8') ;
stdin.addListener('data', (d) => {
    stream += d ;
    console.log('data', d.length) ;
}) ;

stdin.addListener('end', () => {
    let [str1, str2] = stream.split('\n') ;
    let code = str2.charCodeAt(0) ;

    for(let i=1; i<str2.length; i++){
        code += (str2.charCodeAt(i) - str1.charCodeAt(i-1)) ;
    }

    console.log(String.fromCharCode(code)) ;
}) ;
```

Screenshot:

[image: command screenshot]

Can a single listener function can be achieved which has all data instead of adding all in chunks ?